# How to convert Map values to a set in scala

Tags: scala

In a [Map class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html) of Scala, the `keySet` method returns the set of the Map keys.
The collection of map values are not set (as two keys might refer to the same value, so it is a multi-set). The `valuesIterator` method of the Map class returns an iterator, which makes these values traversable, so it is possible to build the set of values of a Map as bellow:

```
val f=Map(1->10,2->15,3->20,4->20,6->20)
val it=f.valuesIterator
var valueSet=Set.empty[Int]
while (it.hasNext){
  valueSet=valueSet+it.next();
}

println(valueSet)  // this will print Set(10, 20, 15)
```

**Question:**

Is there any concise way to get the values of a map as a set?

Comment: I should have considered looking more closely to the available methods of `values`, my bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`toSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce@toSet[B%3E:A]:scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]) method on `TraversableOnce`:

> `def toSet[B >: A]: immutable.Set[B]`
>
> Converts this traversable or iterator to a set.
>   Note: will not terminate for infinite-sized collections.
>
> returns a set containing all elements of this traversable or iterator.

You can use that together with the [`values`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@values:Iterable[B]) or [`valuesIterator`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@valuesIterator:Iterator[B]) method on `Map` by doing `map.values.toSet` or `map.valuesIterator.toSet`.

You might also be interested in the `Set.apply` method that takes a variadic parameter, which can be invoked here as: `Set(map.values.toList:_*)`.

If you ever do need to build a collection iteratively as you have done, you should familiarize yourself with the builder pattern, which allows you to only use a mutable data structure temporarily, and avoid stateful and error-prone `vars`.  For example here you could do `(Set.newBuilder ++= map.values).result`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution just for giggles is to invert the map using `swap` and then grab the `keyset`

```
val myMap = Map(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3))
myMap.map(_.swap).keySet
```